# Javascript context private variables

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create two private variables.

```
 this._popArray, this._popObject
```

They will be accessed by the `populationArray` and `populationObject` variables.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/3jLtqbou/2

I am trying to understand why this is and why uncommenting the code inside `setPopulationArray` fixes it.

```
class Population{
    constructor(size){
        this.size = size;
        this.populationArray = (() => {return getArray.call(this);})();
        this.populationObject = (() => {return getObject.call(this);})();
    }

    initialize(){
        setPopulationArray.call(this);
        setPopulationObject.call(this);
    }
}
// private methods
function getArray(){
    // private variable of the Population class
    if(this._popArray === undefined)
        this._popArray = [];
    return this._popArray;
}

function getObject(){
    // private variable of the Population class
    if(this._popObject === undefined)
        this._popObject = {};
    return this._popObject;
}

function setPopulationArray(){
    this._popArray = Array.apply(null, new Array(this.size)).map(e => new Lek());
    // the code below works as intended. I am trying to understand why the above line does not.
    // let arr = Array.apply(null, new Array(this.size)).map(e => new Lek());
    // arr.forEach((e, i) => getArray.call(this).push(e));
}

function setPopulationObject(){
    this._popArray.forEach(element => getObject.call(this)[element.id] = element);
}
```

Comment: Putting an underscore in front of a property name doesn't make it private - if you want to ensure something isn't accessible elsewhere, use a closure instead.

Comment: Underscore for variables intended to be private is the convention. I am using closures.

Comment: sorry, what is your question?

Comment: what is `new Lek()` ?

Comment: @Icepickle new Array does contain only undefined, that is why I am using Array.apply on it. That is not the problem. `this._popArray` is being set regardless. However, this.populationArray is not set, unless I call `getArray`.

Comment: `(() => {return getArray.call(this);})()` makes no sense. Why don't you write just `getArray.call(this)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = Array.apply(null, new Array(this.size)).map(e => new Lek());
arr.forEach((e, i) => getArray.call(this).push(e));
```

This code works because you are not creating new Array object. 
populationArray holds reference to the firstly created array.

Please check something like this:

```
Array.apply(null, new Array(this.size)).map(e => new Lek())
.forEach((item) => {
    this.populationArray.push(item);
});
```

or change below line to functions which will be return current value of  this._popArray

```
this.populationArray = (() => {return getArray.call(this);})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3jLtqbou/5/